# What was the thing that was blurred out during the 2 super market cash counter scenes?

Tags: it-2017

In the 2017 movie [**It**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1396484/), there are 2 scenes in the super market at the cash counter. The one involving Beverly distracting the cashier and the 2nd where the kid in the hand cast (forgot his name) went to refill his medicine.

In both scenes something on the left side of the cashier(right side of screen) was blurred out. What was it? I saw the movie in India. Was it specific to Indian screening only?

Comment: can you provide us of a screenshot?

Comment: Well, I would have to download it illegally to do that. So sorry

Comment: i was actually wondering the same. i think it may be a cigarette packet box or holder of sorts.. why else would it be blurred ? she smoke cigarettes so i assume its cigarettes. (which are usually available right beside counters)

Comment: I believe cigarettes were on the right side of the cashier from the customers point of view i.e. to the left of the cashier - the question is unclear.

Comment: If it were cigarettes, doesn't Beverly take a pack when the pharmacist was distracted? If that's the case, were they blurred out as well? I don't recall anything being blurred in the US version, so it may be regional.

Comment: Is this generally true, or only in specific nations?  Could be national laws forbidding tobacco advertising (so brand name is blurred), or it could be the movie studio way of not giving out free product placement advertising.

Comment: The only thing on the counter in both scenes is the cigarette stand, but these weren't blurred out in the version I saw in the U.S. so I honestly don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: The cigarette packets seem to have fictional names, so perhaps the CBFC mistakenly thought they were condoms or tampons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I have the answer to my own question.

The thing that was blurred out during the aforementioned two scenes at the cash counter of the super market are boxes of cigarettes
[image]

[image]

Although according to this [news report](http://www.firstpost.com/entertainment/stephen-kings-it-passed-by-cbfc-with-no-cuts-warner-bros-india-thank-prasoon-joshi-4004105.html), there were no cuts ordered. But Indian censors have a rule of showing anti-smoking messages on screen when a character smokes. But usually they don't blur it. It was very unusual.

Comment: +1 for answering. I guess the file makers deemed it less jarring to blur them out than to have a big message displayed across the scene.